# Reference request: Conjugacy classes of real semi-simple Lie group $G$ and their decomposition into $K$-orbits.

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a real semi-simple Lie group and $K$ its maximal compact subgroup.

1. Is there a description of the orbit space of the conjugation action on $G$ by itself?
2. Is there a decription of how a conjugacy class of $G$ decomposes into orbits of the conjugation action by $K$?

I would appreciate it if anyone could point out any references.

Comment: I do not understand the second question but the first is definitely no, just think about the Jordan normal form. JNF does generalize to other semisimple Lie groups.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on item 1, which has just been edited. For item 2, I was asking for how a conjugacy class of $G$ decomposes into orbits of the conjugation action by $K$.